# mysql_num_rows returns zero even though mysql_fetch_array returns results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple mysql query checking the database table 'all_users' for an e-mail which was entered in a text field.

The e-mail is in a variable called `$email`.

In my test case, `$email` is something@yahoo.com and that e-mail exists in the database table.

When I do this:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from all_users where email='$email' ") or die (mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

`$num` is zero even though `$row` is found.

So when I do `echo $row['email'];` it correctly prints out 'something@yahoo.com' but when I do `echo $num;` it's 0!

What am I doing wrong here? I've done this a thousand times but never had this issue.

Comment: Really weird. Change your query to `select * from all_users`
and update us with the result , please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php - Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and **moves the internal data pointer ahead**

So change the order, i.e. first use `mysql_num_rows` and only then do `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Makes sense, but I've done it in this order before and it worked, even when there's only 1 row found. Anyway, thanks, works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse the order of the statements, it will work as you expect. You are retrieving the row from the resource *before* asking it how many rows it has left. Since you are evidently only finding one row, this results in `0`, because you have already retrieved that row.

If you do this it should work:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not because of your `mysqli_num_rows` function, do check the search query, whether it's working or not, otherwise use `trim(column_name)` instead of simply giving column.

It worked for me... it tooks me 2 days to verify it

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you find this question 8 years after it was posted? :)